# Запись шестнадцатеричных чисел в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Первостепенной задачей является формирование файла, в котором на языке Verilog описывается соответствие значения выборок для ЦАП входным значениям шины адреса. 
Для формирования файла используется Python. Ниже представлен код:

```
import math

A = 2**24 - 1
T = 1/(2**8)
n = 0

file = open("D:\TDM\sin.txt","w")

while n < 2**8:

    S = A * 0.7 / 2 * math.sin(2 * math.pi * T * n) + A / 2

    file.write("if(addr = 8'd" + str(n) + ")" + "out_sample <= 24'd" + str(S) + "; \n")
    n += 1

file.close()
```

В итоге получается файл, фрагмент содержимого которого представлен ниже в формате Verilog:

```
введите if(addr = 8'd0)out_sample <= 24'd8388607.5; 
if(addr = 8'd1)out_sample <= 24'd8532714.21355256; 
if(addr = 8'd2)out_sample <= 24'd8676734.122609375; 
if(addr = 8'd3)out_sample <= 24'd8820580.474962479; 
if(addr = 8'd4)out_sample <= 24'd8964166.622947972; 
if(addr = 8'd5)out_sample <= 24'd9107406.075639347; 
if(addr = 8'd6)out_sample <= 24'd9250212.550946364; 
if(addr = 8'd7)out_sample <= 24'd9392500.02758818; 
if(addr = 8'd8)out_sample <= 24'd9534182.796909336; 
if(addr = 8'd9)out_sample <= 24'd9675175.514507454; 
if(addr = 8'd10)out_sample <= 24'd9815393.251641508;
```

Скрипт работает как нужно, но числа представляются в десятичном формате. Для большей читабельности данного фрагмента кода, необходимо преобразовать данные числа в шестнадцатеричные.
Но в случае использования команды

```
hex()
```

Допустим число 1 будет иметь вид 0x1. 
Как получить значение без приставки "0x" а так же преобразовать их к единому отображению для 8 разрядных чисел?

То есть необходимо получить не 0x1, а 01, что бы сформировать число для Verilog формата 8'h01.

Comment: `"{:x}".format(n)`; прочитай про синтаксис format() — им будет намного комфортней всю строку формировать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open(r'd:\tmp\all-bytes-hex.txt', 'w') as file:
    for octet in range(0x100):
        print(f"8'h{octet:02x}", file=file)
```

Результат:

```
8'h00
8'h01
...
8'hfe
8'hff
```

[Больше `format()` примеров](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples).

Comment: Можете пояснить первую строку? (with open(r'd:\tmp\all-bytes-hex.txt', 'w') as file:)

Comment: @АлексейВоронов если не знаете что with-конструкция в Питоне делает, то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос.